# VBS : conditional column filling in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am new to VB Scripting. I am trying to write a code here which will insert three new columns and thereafter in one of the existing columns it will check for a Condition (specified in the code) and will fill one of the new columns depending on the value. However here I am getting multiple errors . Can anyone help me out by guiding me in the right direction ?

P.S- the Working code is as follows. Answer to the same are in the comments.

```
     Const xlToRight = -4161
const xlColumns = &H2 
const xlLinear = -4132 
const xlDay = 1

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Application.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Qualysrep.xlsx")
Set objSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("F1").EntireColumn
    objRange.Insert(xlShiftToRight)

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("G1").EntireColumn
    objRange.Insert(xlShiftToRight)

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("H1").EntireColumn
    objRange.Insert(xlShiftToRight)

objsheet.Cells(11,6) = "DeviceType"
objsheet.Cells(11,7) = "Domain"
objsheet.Cells(11,8) = "Status in AD"


Dim DeviceType 
Dim OS 
Dim lastrowrange 
Dim i 
lastrowrange = objSheet.Range("A65536").End(-4162).Row
Set DeviceType = objsheet.Range("F1",objsheet.Cells(lastrowrange, 22))
Set OS = objsheet.Range("J1",objsheet.Cells(lastrowrange, 22))
For i = 1 to lastrowrange
    If OS.Cells(i,1).Value = "Windows 2012 Standard" Then
        DeviceType.Cells(i,1).Value = "Server"
        Else
        DeviceType.Cells(i,1).Value = "Not a Server"
    End If
Next 


objWorkbook.Close True
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: On which line(s)?

Comment: On which lines are you getting the errors?  Are lines highlighted somehow?

Comment: It's on the Line <39,6> Microsoft VBScript Compilation Error: Expected end of statement. The line 39 is the line - Next i

Comment: Why have you tagged this as a VBA question? It would appear to VBS?

Comment: My bad. Changed it to VBS

Comment: Use `Next` instead of `Next i`. VBScript has many vagaries and that is one of of them. You might want to learn powershell instead.

Comment: I had started with Powershell but got confused as I was unable to find many functionalities that VBS offers in Powershell. Can you suggest any good tutorial for Powershell in Excel ? Also when I remove i from NEXT ; I get a new error : Error on line 30,1 - 

> Microsoft VBscript Runtime Error : Object Required 'A65536'.

P.S. - The line 30 is `lastrowrange = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I can't see where you have defined `xlUp` ... VBS won't recognise VBA constants. So you have to define it. `xlUp = -4162`. Also, use `Sheet.Range("A65536").End(-4162).Row`

Comment: Hi Pankaj ; I tried the same but the same error persists.

Comment: You used `objSheet.Range("A65536").End(-4162).Row`? Is the error on same line or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry not the same error but I get an error on Error on line 31,1 - > Microsoft VBscript Runtime Type mismatch: 'Cells'.

Comment: Its because Cells is VBA.. for vbs, you have to attach it with the sheet ... try `objSheet.Cells`

Comment: You will avoid most of the errors, if you simply attach the sheet specific code with that sheet in vbs. for e.g. `Set DeviceType = Range("F1",Cells(lastrowrange, 22))` will fail as vbscript do not know what Range and Cells are. If you attach the sheet object, your code will work

Comment: Pankaj ; as per the suggestion. I changed the code to objsheet ref and it started working fine. Thank you so much for the help :)